# How can I fix Electron app not launching properly?

Tags: electron

- After launching the app I **can’t interact with the loaded html page**:
  mouse pointer won’t affect elements with hover class and scripts
  won’t load content.
- Minimizing and then maximizing the window will make the page behave normally.
- This issue occurs only if **show** is set to **false** and [window is shown after the app is loaded](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#showing-window-gracefully).

I tried using the workaround by openning DevTools after showing the window which will force the app to launch properly:

```
mainWindow.once(‘ready-to-show’, () => {
 mainWindow.show()
 mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
})
```

To me it seems like the app window appears in the background, however, adding the win.focus() method doesn’t make any difference. Is there any possible way to workaround this issue without setting show to true?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: are you waiting for the app [Event: 'ready'](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-ready) before creating your window?

```
app.on('ready', function () {
    // create your windows
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by removing the **maximizable** option which was previously set to **false**. After that app started to load properly.

I now use the **win.setMaximizable(false)** method to prevent the app window from being maximized after it's already been loaded and shown.